# Windows option not showing up in the boot menu (Dual boot)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-8

I have installed ubuntu installed while ago. Windows 10 was previously running . One of my co worker  was helping me dual booting ubuntu .But he probably messed it up somewhere probably ended up installing it in C drive . After installation Ubuntu was acting weird screen flipped upside down this sort thing . Some of my other team mates some how quick fix the issue and told me to uninstall the windows part . I haven't used windows part since then .(I just switched PC so there wasn't anything important ) but I am running out of space in ubuntu right now ,wish to get windows back! I have noticed when I boot my pc there is no windows option to choose from .I can only window recovery option side by side ubuntu . Anybody knows how to solve this ? I don't have much experience ,in partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get rid of the Windows Partition?

If so try using GParted, this will allow you to lookup for the NTFS partitions and delete it, since this is the Windows Partition, aftermath just apply your newly available data you got from windows to your ubuntu partition.

GParted it really intuitive so no need to use cls, go ahead and try it.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/PRAJhL6 Hi brother .Can you guide me through now?

Comment: NTFS and FAT32 seem to be windows partitions, also your ext4 partition that has 47GB used, seems to be that;s the one of your ubuntu partition, select that partition and enlarge the size of it, in order to do that you have to unmount and mount the partition or if Im not wrong you actuallly have to do it from a liveUSB partition in order to avoid damages into the partition

Comment: Yeah ,I was wondering the same think . How can I allocate the unused portion of 600 GB to my  linux os .?

Comment: Start your computer from a liveUSB bootable drive like ubuntu, could be the iso you used to install the OS, so, aftermath lookup for your ext4 partition and drag it to the sides to make it larger or just type a larger number, if you have any issue reply back, also if possible verify if this solves your issue or this is your answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to take the following steps:

1. Backup any data that is too important to you to risk losing.
2. Run Gparted from a live disk.
3. Extend sda1 into the unallocated area.
4. You will probably find sda5 and sda6 are now at the start of sda1 (i.e. the left hand end). Move sda6 all the way to the right.
5. Extend sda5 into the unallocated space between sda5 and sda6. Job done!

If you have no intention of ever going back to windows you can delete sda2 and sda3 before step 3 and use the extra space for Ubuntu. If you do try to recover windows using sda2 and sda3 it may wipe Ubuntu.